# How to configure clang++ and VS Code on a mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, clang, intellisense

I'm trying to develop C++ code in VS Code on a mac.  I have **no problems** building and debugging.  However, my editor **is full of red ink**.  **Is there a way to fix my editor** so it is as smart as the compiler?

Here's a simple example:  https://github.com/TradeIdeasPhilip/compress/tree/master/mac-os/eight. I can open this folder in VS code and build and run, but the editor is ugly.

One of the first error messages is on line 22 of EightShared.C:

```
const std::string preloadContents = "\xdc\xe4\xeb\xf1\xf6\xfa\xfd\xff";
```

This should be very straightforward.  It's a string constant.  I'm importing `<string>` through another header file.  (And adding  directly to the top of this file did not make a difference.) But VS code marks the first `:` in red and when I hover over it I see `expected a ;` and when I ask it to help me, it offers to disable the red squiggles.

The editor also complains about the `class` keyword on line 31 even though it accepts classes in other files.

The editor also complains about most (but not all) references to types like `uint32_t` even though I `#include <stdint.h>` and that works without any red ink.  Here's an example from EightShared.h
[image]
[image]
[image]
Those are just a couple of samples.  My editor is filled with red marks.

I'm using Microsoft's C++ extensions for VS Code.  I'm guessing that one of these needs to be configured better.
[image]

**Any thoughts on how to get rid of all of these red marks?  Maybe a sample of a working config file or a suggestion of what I'm doing wrong?**  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found a problem in my [.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json](https://github.com/TradeIdeasPhilip/compress/blob/e76542bbaa4e83ee65bbd7860f5f780acd7dfb5b/mac-os/eight/.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json#L7) file.  I removed `"/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1"` from the `"includePath"`.  Then intellisense started working again.

I have no idea how that line got into that file.  I certainly didn't type it.

[The change in GitHub](https://github.com/TradeIdeasPhilip/compress/commit/4daec3735c4d25cabcbd7011ab9440f893ff0850).